# How does one obtain a boolean value given a variable having a value 'Y' or 'N' in Python 3?

Tags: python

I get an input as 'Y' or 'N'.  I need to convert that to True if 'Y'or False otherwise.  I came across this construct for this purpose.  The code works but I do not know what it is called.

```
    goto = "Y"
    __goto = (False,True)[goto=="Y"]
```

Can someone explain how this works ? And what this construct is called ?

Comment: That is overcomplicated. `goto=="Y"` already gives you what you need. The implicit conversion to an integer to then look up the same value you already had in a tuple is completely unnecessary.

Comment: @Kemp I agree, I was about to write the same thing.

Comment: A related, but more interesting example would be the built-in `cmp()` in Python.

Comment: @DanielHao The question is specifically about Python 3. `cmp()` is a built-in in Python 2, but was removed in Python 3.0.1, and was only in 3.0.0 by mistake.

Comment: I understand that. It's just mentioned here for some reference.

Comment: The construct `__goto = (False,True)[goto=="Y"]` was how we used to do it in Python up to 2.4 (2006). Sadly, there are some very dated recommendations out there that do not carry a sell-by date.

Answer (score 3):

That is overcomplicated - `goto=="Y"` already gives you what you need.

If you want to know how the code in question works, `goto=="Y"` gives you True or False. This is then used to index into a tuple (`(False, True)`) because the booleans can be used as ints (False = 0, True = 1). This then gives you back the same value you already had.

Effectively if `goto` is `"Y"` then you get

```
(False, True)[True]  => (False, True)[1]
```

and if `goto` is anything else you get

```
(False, True)[False]  => (False, True)[0]
```

Comment: To be precise, `True`/`False` is not converted to an integer. Boolean is a subclass of integer in python

Comment: ``bool`` is a sub-class of ``int``, with ``True`` and ``False`` being constants, that behave like integers in numeric contexts. You can even do math with them: ``3*True + False + True`` (result here is ``4``).

Answer (score 0):

```
goto = "Y"
```

You assign "Y" to `goto` which eval to `True` in the next line.

`(False,True)` is a tuple and you accesing it with an index `[goto=="Y"]`

Then `True` is eval as `1` for index access, hence `__goto` is `True`.

```
__goto = (False,True)[goto=="Y"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Although, there are multiple approaches to solve the problem but all of them I see are either complicated or just plain unreadable.

I would suggest you to use simple dict for this.

```
response_dict = {"Y" : True, "N" : False}
response = "Y"
print(response_dict.get(response, None))
```

This is future proof as well, as you can add more keys to it.